# Understanding the proof that the trivial $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$ is unique.

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Question:

Let $G$ be a finite group. Find a $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$ which is isomorphic to the trivial $\mathbb{C}G$-module. Is there only one such $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule?

Answer:

Let $V = sp( \sum_{g \in G}  g ) $. Then V is a trivial $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$. Now suppose that $U$ is an arbitrary trivial $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$, so $U = sp(u)$ for some $u$. Then $gu=u$ for all $g \in G$, so $u|G| = (\sum_{g\in G}g)u = u(\sum_{g\in G}g) \in V$. Thus $U=V$, and so $\mathbb{C}G$ has exactly one trivial $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule, namely $V$.

My questions:

What is the definition of a trivial submodule?

Why does $U$ being a trivial submodule mean it is generated by a single generator, $u$?

Why does $(\sum_{g\in G}g)u = u(\sum_{g\in G}g)$?

Comment: I doubt "trivial" means "cyclic". Normally here I think it would mean "zero submodule" but that is apparently not the intention. The next candidate is "simple submodule", but there will be lots of simple submodules, not just 1.  So my best guess is that it means there is only one minimal submodule isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as a $\mathbb CG$ module

Comment: Apparently it means that $G$ acts like the identity on this simple submodule.(?)

Comment: That sounds right, I have another question that says "Find a trivial $\mathbb{C}G$-submodule (on which $G$ acts trivially)." So I assume $G$ acting like the identity means $G$ acts trivially, means the submodule is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, a trivial submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$ is a simple submodule on which elements of $G$ act trivially. That is, if $V$ is a trivial submodule and $v\in V$ then $gv=v$.

Now, given this definition, it is clear that any trivial submodule must be one dimensional. Indeed, if $U\subset\mathbb{C}G$ is a trivial submodule and $u\in U$ is nonzero, then the 1-dimensional subspace $\mathbb{C}u$ is a proper $G$-submodule (since $gu=u$ for all $g\in G$). Hence $\mathbb{C}u=U$.

Now, write $u=\sum_{h\in G}\lambda_hh$ for some $\lambda_h\in \mathbb{C}$. To see that $u\left(\sum_g g\right)=\left(\sum_g g\right)u$ it is enough to observe that
$$h\left(\sum_{g\in G} g\right)=\left(\sum_{g\in G} g\right)h$$
for every $h\in G$. To this end, note that
$$h\left(\sum_{g\in G} g\right)=\left(\sum_{g\in G} hg\right)=\left(\sum_{g\in G} (hgh^{-1})h\right)=\left(\sum_{g\in G} (hgh^{-1})\right)h.$$
However, the map $g\mapsto hgh^{-1}$ is a bijection $G\to G$, so
$$\sum_{g\in G} (hgh^{-1})=\sum_{g\in G}g$$
as required.

Comment: An alternative way to see it, using some more high-powered machinery is that since $\mathbb{C}G$ is semisimple, any composition factors occurs the same number of times as its dimension. An even more high-powered way to see it is section 6.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06975

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sure, you can prove the multiplicity result either way, but I believe the OP's question is "why does $u$ commute with $\sum g$?"

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just thought I would comment on the more advanced way to do it (mainly because the first one was what immediately came to me, but then I realized that it also followed from the second one which is a bit silly to use for this).